# api POST Auth always returns 200 but has a 401 error

Tags: api, authentication, post, error-handling, httpresponse

Let me first say that I have researched extensively and have no clue whats happening to why when I login with the "wrong" password or user the network Auth status says 200 but the console reports the error: Invalid username or password. So it shows the correct error but has a 200 status which is incorrect. The status should be 401.

alternatively, when I put in the correct information it correct credentials it gives me the token as expected. The problem is the 200 status when it should be a 401 status. please help me figure out why the status is not returning correctly. AND YES IT NEEDS to return 401 so that another part of my code performs correctly.

Here is an image of what it says:

[image: the Devtools]

Here is my POST Authorization code (minus my DB connection- which connects):

```
 <?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
   if ($_GET['url'] == "auth") {
    } else if ($_GET['url'] == "users") {
   }
   } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
     if ($_GET['url'] == "auth") {
       $postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
       $postBody = json_decode($postBody);
       $username = $postBody->username;
       $password = $postBody->password;
    if ($db->query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
        if (password_verify($password, $db->query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'])) {
            $cstrong = True;
            $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
            $user_id = $db->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
            $db->query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES (\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));
            echo '{ "Token": "'.$token.'" }';
        } else {
            echo '{ "Error": "Invalid username or password!" }';
            http_response_code(401);
        }
     } else {
        echo '{ "Error": "Invalid username or password!" }';
        http_response_code(401);
     }
 }

 } 
 ?>
```

Here is my form code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#login').click(function() {

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "api/auth",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: '{ "username": "'+ $("#username").val() +'", "password": "'+ $("#password").val() +'" }',
            success: function(r) {
                console.log(r)
            }

        });
    });
 </script>
```

Also this is what dev says:

Request URL: http://ustylz.com/api/auth
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: xx.xx.1xx.2xx:xx
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

I expect when I click $login button with the incorrect username or password then the DEVtools in chrome will show Auth in red and have a 401 status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "header" after echo or any output. http_response_code attempts to insert a header parameter after you echoed the error. Thus, the response code is 200 and in your server log file you will find a warning about this issue (unless errors are disabled).

Comment: Question: if I disable errors can I keep it written as is? And if so how can I disable the errors without screwing up anything

Comment: Just write the headers before the error message (swap the lines), and you are done :-)

Comment: Thanks u saved me so much time